# How to debug quickly in phoenix/elixir?

Tags: debugging, elixir, phoenix-framework

As I am learning Elixir/Phoenix, I happen to run into an issue like this often.

The problem is that this comes from a dependency, so normally I do this:

- open `deps/something/.../thefile.ex`
- add some debug code like `IO.inspect` to see what params are being passed
- stop server, recompile with `mix deps.recompile something`
- check the documentation to see what types are expected to that function
- compare the types and trace down the problem to my code

This works but I'd like to improve my process, I know I can use Iex to start a repl, but I'd like to get much faster in terms of:

- having a repl inside of the error page itself started automatically (like in better_errors gem for Rails)
- having a way to see what arguments went into that method without me digging around (could be solved by the former point)
- being able to see a method's documentation quickly

Also any other tips are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to see at least the arguments in the terminal. A line like this: `(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Keyword.pop/3
        (elixir) lib/keyword.ex:828: Keyword.pop(%{}, :a, nil)`

Comment: You can also compile individual files in the terminal without restarting the server by issuing the command `c`, for example: `c "file-name"` (although I'm not sure if they observe changes in configuration).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please open up an issue in Plug: https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug

You have some great suggestions, like accessing the docs and make the arguments explicit. I don't think we can provide a REPL at the place of error though.

EDIT 1: I went ahead and [opened an issue here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/issues/552) since I got excited about those improvements! :D

EDIT 2: I realize that I should probably have used a comment as this is not quite an answer (yet!)